# CloudFront - How to forward all request headers to the origin

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

At CloudFront behaviour setting, is "All" the one to forward all request headers to the origin?

[image]

- [Values That You Specify When You Create or Update a Distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesMinTTL)

> If you configure CloudFront to **forward all headers to your origin** for a cache behavior, CloudFront never caches the associated objects. Instead, CloudFront forwards all requests for those objects to the origin. In that configuration, the value of Minimum TTL must be 0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is.

The documentation seems to focus more on caching based on headers and less on what's forwarded, but caching on headers and forwarding headers to the origin go hand-in-hand.

As I was looking for clear citations from the documentation, one reference I found in the *Amazon CloudFront Developer Guide* is the one shown below.  It's a link to a section titled *"Cache Based on Selected Request Headers"* but its anchor tag is *DownloadDistValuesForwardHeaders*.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesForwardHeaders

This suggests that someone has tried to clarify or simplify the documemtation... with apparently limited success.

Note that this forwards *almost* all headers to the origin, except for some that are still [stripped](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior) for security and/or operational reasons, like `X-Forwarded-Proto`, `X-Real-IP`, and `X-Edge-*`.

Note also that if your origin protocol is HTTPS and you were not already whitelisting the `Host` header at CloudFront, then whitelisting all headers will potentially change the requirements for the origin's TLS certificate. Failure to handle this correctly is one of several reasons why CloudFront might return a [502 error](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-502-bad-gateway.html#ssl-negotitation-failure) to the viewer.

Answer (score 2):

The layout has changed a bit since this question was asked and answered.

In the "behavior" settings, it is now necessary to select "Legacy cache settings" for these options to be visible.  You can select "all" or a specific set of headers to forward.  Below are a set of headers that allow websocket connections to work:

[image]